# ¿cómo puedo alojar 2 archivos js en la nube y llamarlos desde mi codigo html

Tags: javascript, html, base-de-datos, web

lo que pasa es que tengo una pagina con html y la tengo alojada en un servidor de la empresa, el problema es que ese servidor no permite almacenar archivos .JS  por tal motivo creo que la solución es alojar esos 2 archivos JS en otra plataforma como google drive o dropbox. no se si se puede o si hay alguna otra pagina que pueda realizar eso.

Comment: puedes intentar subir tus js en jsDelivr, solo te creas una cuenta. solo ten mucho cuidado de no publicar información sensible como contraseñas o cadenas de conexión

Comment: Ya probaste hacerlo como se hace con los CDN de jquery entre otros?